# How to Stop Sticky Footer at Content DIV

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I've been tweaking my sticky footer in hopes of stopping it once it hits the `#body` div, but so far, I've been unsuccessful. In most cases, it doesn't usually cover the content, but [on this page](http://www.caseykidd.com/music.html), it often does.

I would like to keep it stuck to the bottom of the window, if possible, but the only other solution I've been able to come up with is a fixed position. Any suggestions?

Comment: and why dont just use fixed ?

Comment: To me, it looks cleaner when my "Copyright" is always stuck to the bottom of the window, versus riding the coat-tail of my content (especially with a background image).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can apply a fixed position/sticky footer in a number of ways. One option is using only CSS, as [Twitter Bootstraps Sticky Footer example](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html). That is probably the simplest implementation.

```
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
  html,body { height: 100%; }

  /* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
  #wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -100px; /* Negative indent footer by it's height */
  }

  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  #push,#footer{ height:100px }
  #footer {}
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of the `#push` div. What's the logic there?

Comment: Read Elias post. His method is very similar and he explains the #push element. It also prevents content from overlapping the footer.

Comment: @darcher that's because it's the same method, just in the original context. The sticky footer for twitter bootstrap utilizes the same footer that I provided, it's just the original source. One of those give credit where credit is due situations.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your desired result, but may be what you need is just like:

```
#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't prevent a collision with my content. If the window resizes, I would want the footer to drop off at the bottom of my content div.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ryan Fait](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) you can use the following CSS in the document layout.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em; /*-4em represents the height of the footer */
 }
 .footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
 }
```

As well as the following HTML markup, which is actually quite simple to implement and it works in all major browsers.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Your website content here.</p>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>Website Footer Here.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've implemented it before and it works flawlessly for having a footer either stick to the bottom of the page, or at the bottom of your content, and it requires no jquery or javascript at all.

To respond to kurzweilguy's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259636/how-to-stop-sticky-footer-at-content-div/16260045#comment23266515_16259924), the push makes it so that you can have the footer at `100%` height, this would naturally extend the page to have a scroll bar, so to counter it you put a negative margin on it to bring it back up to make it fit on the bottom of the page. The footer that [darcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2134533/darcher) references uses the same exact footer. It's a very nicely compiled footer!