# Trying to get .footer to remain at the very bottom of webpage

Tags: html, css, css-position, footer

My HTML looks like the following, without the content though as the following is only needed to answer my question:

```
<html> 
  <body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="socialmedia"></div>
      <div class="navbar"></div>
      <div class="mainbody></div>
      <div class="footer"></div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to get my footer to remain at the bottom of my webpage, beneath .mainbody. The problem though, is that the footer seems to sit at the bottom of my window only, not at the bottom of the webpage which could extend well below my actual window when I have a lot of content. Right now, I have all the div's above set to position "absolute"; as well the html and body are styled in the following way:

```
html, body{
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
html {  background: url(/img/multiblock.png)repeat center center fixed; }
```

}

Now, the only way I can get my footer to remain at the bottom of the webpage is to set top:-3998px (or whatever the height of my largest window is). Obviously this won't work once a webpage has enough content on it to expand it past that height. If I set position to relative, it appears at the top of my whole webpage and when positioned absolute it appears at the bottom of the viewable window only. You can check out the website at http://www.edmuncovered.com to see what I mean or to check the rest of the code. Parts of my website include adding content every day or so so I want to make sure the webpage can increase in height with added content, but that the formatting stays the same and the footer obviously stays at the bottom. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need...

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Thanks rousseauo... I ended up figuring out that I had to rid almost all of my div's of their positioning and work from scratch again to find which one's really needed to be positioned absolute (ended up only being the footer, leaving the rest as static or relative) and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

CSS:

```
.socialmedia, .navbar, .mainbody, .footer
{
border: 1px solid grey;
margin-top: 5px; 
width: 800px;
}
.socialmedia
{
height: 20px;
}
.mainbody
{
min-height: 980px;
}
.footer
{
height: 25px;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="socialmedia">Social Media</div>
    <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
    <div class="mainbody">Mainbody</div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**Working jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/LrfXr/

Comment: You can set the '.mainbody {min-height: 980px;}' to the minimum height that you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is a questions similar to the one here: [How to Stop Sticky Footer at Content DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259636/how-to-stop-sticky-footer-at-content-div/16259924#16259924)

At which there are a few good answers.

Links on that page:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Basically you're looking for a footer that attaches itself to the bottom of the viewport but also extends should the content push it off the viewport. Martin Bean and Ryan Fait have the best methods of this. The bootstrap's method is a variation of this method too.

Happy hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRNPy/24/) link. Followings are your css and html code:

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="socialmedia">Social Media</div>
      <div class="navbar">Navbar</div>
    <div class="mainbody">Mainbody</br>Mainbody</br>Mainbody</br>Mainbody</div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
   </div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
body {  
    background-color:#E4E2E2; 
    color:#fff;
}
.container {
   min-height:100%;
   /*position:relative;*/
}
.socialmedia {
    background-color:#186301;
    padding:10px;
}
.navbar {
   background:#A60206;
   padding:10px;
   min-height:30px;
}
.mainbody {
   padding:20px;
   background-color:#6D0594;
}
.footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   padding:2%;
   background-color:#000;
   width:96%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:
http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

In short, use this:

**CSS**

```
* {
   margin: 0;
}
   html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
  height: 4em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body> </html>
```